# How to update all values of One2many field in Table for Odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, append, onchange, odoo-10, one2many

I have a One2many field in inventory for product pack. And I want that all fields values of that One2many field should update in fields of One2many field in sales order, row and column wise. So, Anyone can help me.

**My Python code is here:**

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):

    _inherit = "product.template"


 product_pack = fields.One2many('product.pack', 'template_id', string='Product Pack', copy=True)

class ProductDesign(models.Model):

    _description = 'Product Pack'

    _name = "product.pack"

    _rec_name = "product_id"



    check_option = fields.Boolean('#')

    template_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string='Template', required="True", ondelete='cascade', index=True, copy=True)

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product', required="True", domain="[('is_pack','=',False)]")

    services = fields.Many2one('gold.service')

    qty = fields.Integer('Quantity', default=1)
```

**Here in 'wizard' (One2many field table) i want to update all fields (row and column) of product_pack**

```
class SalePackWizard(models.TransientModel):

    _name = "sale.pack.wizard"

    _description = "Sale Pack Wizard"


 product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="Product Pack", required=True, domain="[('is_pack','=',True)]")

    wizard = fields.One2many('product.gold','service')


 @api.onchange('product_id')

    def _onchange_product_pack_name(self):

         for w in self.product_id.product_pack:

            for s in w:

                print "s:", s.product_id.name, s.services, s.qty

                r = []

                print"r:", r


class ProductDesign(models.Model):

    _description = 'Product Pack'

    _name = "product.gold"

    _rec_name = "products_ids"



    service= fields.Many2one('product.val', string='Templates', required="True", ondelete='cascade', index=True, copy=True)

    check_box = fields.Boolean('#')

    products_ids = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product', required="True", domain="[('is_pack','=',False)]")

    services = fields.Many2one('gold.service')

    qtyy = fields.Integer('Quantity', default=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved.

**Here is the function code of problem:**

```
wizard = fields.One2many('product.gold','service',change_default=True, default=_onchange_action_product_add)



@api.onchange('product_id')

    def _onchange_action_product_add(self):

        res = self.product_id.product_pack

        r = []

        value = {}

        for var in self.product_id.product_pack:

            print "var:::", var

            for line in self.product_id.product_pack:

                print "line:::", line , line.product_id, line.product_id.name, line.qty, line.services, line.id

                data = {'products_ids': line.product_id.id,

                        'service':var.id, #many2one child field from one2many field

                        'services':line.services,

                        'qtyy': line.qty

                        }

                print "data:", data

                r.append((0, 0, data))

                print "r.append", r.append, r

                #return data

            value.update(wizard=r)

            return {'value': value}
```